# how to validate vSelect using vuelidate in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have industryErrors() function in computed. My vuelidate validations are working perfect for v-text-field and v-textarea. It is only not working for v-select .. not error is shown, when submitted empty.

```
<v-select 
    v-model="industry"
    items="industryList"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="val"
    :error-messages="industryErrors"
    label="Industry"
    :reduce="name => name.val"
    @input="$v.industry.$touch()"
    @blur="$v.industry.$touch()"
    required
    >
</v-select>
```

Comment: What is the content of `industryErrors`?

Comment: Can you show your error function ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, exactly setup like the example on vuetify but it's not working! Btw, `@input="$v.industry.$touch()"` should be `@change="$v.industry.$touch()"`

Comment: Hi, How do you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late for this, but if it's helpful for someone, It worked for me:

```js
import { maxLength, minLength, required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  name: 'ServiceCar',
  validations: {
    editedItem: {
      category: { required }
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    editedItem: {},
    categories: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']
  }),
  computed: {
    categoryErrors () {
      if (!this.$v.editedItem.category.required &&  this.$v.editedItem.category.$dirty) {
        return 'This field is required'
      } else return []
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<v-select
  v-model="editedItem.category"
  required
  :items="categories"
  prepend-icon="mdi-car-multiple"
  :error-messages="categoryErrors"
  solo
  @click="$v.editedItem.category.$touch()"
>
  <template #label>
     Category 
    <span class="red--text"><strong> *</strong></span>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

[Final result after the implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkkoH.png)